# Using sed replace an exact word

Tags: linux, sed

I want to find and replace 3600 using sed, but it's replacing all the occurrences that match. I only want to replace 3600 and 3600 can occur anywhere in the file.

Text file content example:

```
expr: time() - somerandometext > 3600*25
expr: time() - somerandometext > 3600
```

The output i get after running the command

```
sed -e 's/\<3600\>/21600/g' file.txt
```

Output

```
expr: time() - somerandometext > 21600*25
expr: time() - somerandometext > 21600
```

Desired Output

```
expr: time() - somerandometext > 3600*25
expr: time() - somerandometext > 21600
```

Comment: The conditions under which you want to match it literally are unclear. The word boundaries match on the `*` just like on a space or end of line. If you can limit yourself to "only when surrounded by a space or beginning/end of line" that would look like `(^| )3600( |$)` but not all `sed` dialects can cope with that, and then you will want to restore the space you matched. So try `s/(^| )3600( |$)/\121600\2/g` but no guarantees. Your precise OS and `sed` version might be helpful to include if you need further help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With most `sed`s:

```
sed -E 's/(^|[[:blank:]])3600([[:blank:]]|$)/\121600\2/' file
```

Or perl:

```
perl -pE 's/(?<=^|\h)3600(?=\h|$)/21600/g' file
```

Or awk:

```
awk '{for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) if ($i=="3600") $i="21600"} 1' file
```

Any of those prints:

```
expr: time() - somerandometext > 3600*25
expr: time() - somerandometext > 21600
```

Your attempt with sed:

```
sed -e 's/\<3600\>/21600/g' file.txt
```

Is using `\<` and `\>` which is the GNU sed extension for word breaks. This fails since for one or both reasons here:

1. The example has `' 3600*'` and that satisfies a word break on both sides;
2. You are using a sed other than GNU sed.